# Print array of return values in ajax success

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to print array of values in ajax success

my controller code is

```
function get_all_packages() {        
    $data['free_flow'] = $this->Api_model->get_free_flow_packages();
    $data['draft'] = $this->Api_model->get_draft_packages();
    print_r($data);
}
```

my model code is

```
function get_free_flow_packages(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('item');        
    $this->db->where('item.category_id', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return Json_encode($query->result_array());
}
```

my ajax code is

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
                   alert('hello');
                   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 
      "http://localhost/bartender_api/Api/get_all_packages/",                            
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log(result.free_flow); 
                            console.log(result.draft);

                        }
                    });
               });
```

here i will console both array value but it showing null,how to print both array values.

Comment: try using `dataType:'json'` in **ajax options**

Comment: i will try but, not return any value

Comment: if i use console.log(result) without dataType:'json'   it will return

Comment: Array
(
    [free_flow] => [{"id":"16","name":"Non Alcoholic Free Flow","category_id":"1","price":"0","quantity":"","country":"","order_multiple_of":"0","minimum_order":"0"},{"id":"17","name":"Beer and Wine free flow","category_id":"1","price":"0","quantity":"","country":"","order_multiple_of":"0","minimum_order":"0"},]
)

Comment: Is returning any data if you load http://localhost/bartender_api/Api/get_all_packages/?

Comment: yes this data will return              Array ( [free_flow] => [{"id":"16","name":"Non Alcoholic Free Flow","category_id":"1","price":"0","quantity":"","country":"","order_multiple_of":"0","minimum_order":"0"},{"id":"17","name":"Beer and Wine free flow","category_id":"1","price":"0","quantity":"","country":"","order_multiple_of":"0","minimum_order":"0"},] )

Comment: Oh you're adding a comma at the end of the `id:17` (end of json, it's invalid)

Comment: Then how i will print this data

Comment: you can't if you have an invalid json... so, if you fix it, probably you may able to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `print_r` in your controller function, use

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

and in your ajax add property `dataType:"JSON"`
Then you can access `free_flow` as `result.free_flow`

Answer (score 0):

Try with some changes

Controller

```
echo $data;
```

Model

It's `json_encode` not `Json_encode()`

```
 return json_encode($query->result_array());
```

Ajax request (Addition)

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: I think PHP functions are case-insensitive. So `json_encode` and `Json_encode` do not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Add ajax options:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

You can also use codeigniter native output class to show real json data:

```
$this->output->set_content_type("application/json")->set_output($data);
```